# Bazel targets built against TensorFlow C++ API don't execute factory registration functions

Tags: c++, tensorflow, linker, bazel

I am encountering an issue that seems to be identical to the one described here: https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/+/v1.4.0/tensorflow/docs_src/mobile/linking_libs.md#global-constructor-magic

> One of the subtlest problems you may run up against is the “No session factory registered for the given session options” error when trying to call TensorFlow from your own application.
> ... TensorFlow uses a registration pattern in a lot of places:
>
> ```
> class RegisterMul {
>  public:
>   RegisterMul() {
>     global_kernel_registry()->Register(“Mul”, [](){
>       return new MulKernel()
>     });
>   }
> };
> RegisterMul g_register_mul;
> ```
>
> This sets up a class RegisterMul with a constructor that tells the global kernel registry what function to call when somebody asks it how to create a “Mul” kernel. Then there’s a global object of that class, and so the constructor should be called at the start of any program.
>
> The global object that’s defined is not used by any other code, so linkers not designed with this in mind will decide that it can be deleted. As a result, the constructor is never called, and the class is never registered.
>
> The solution is to force the linker to not strip any code from the library, even if it believes it’s unused. On iOS, this step can be accomplished with the `-force_load` flag, specifying a library path, and on Linux you need `--whole-archive`. These persuade the linker to not be as aggressive about stripping, and should retain the globals.

However, I'm having trouble turning "on Linux you need `--whole-archive`" into something that actually works.  I am:

- Compiling TensorFlow 2.2.2 from source into a python wheel
- Using that wheel in another project built with bazel
- Exposing that wheel's C++ API via a bazel target (see below)
- Referencing that C++ API target from custom C++ code

I've tried adding:

```
alwayslink=True,
linkopts = ["-Wl,--whole-archive"],
```

to the bazel targets for each of the my targets in the above list, and it has not made a difference. My target for the wheel is:

```
cc_library(
    name = "c_api",
    # This is the only .so or .so.* in the wheel
    srcs=["//:tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so.2"],
    hdrs = glob([
        "tensorflow/include/**/*.h",
        "tensorflow/include/**/*.inc",
        "tensorflow/include/**/Eigen/**/*",
    ]),
    alwayslink=True,
    linkopts = ["-Wl,--whole-archive"],
    includes = [
        "tensorflow/include",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    deps = ["@zoox//third_party/cuda:cuda_libs"],
)
```

And the actual end target that's failing:

```
cc_library(
    name = "tensorflow_wrapper",
    srcs = ["tensorflow_wrapper.cpp"],
    hdrs = ["tensorflow_wrapper.h"],
    tags = ["offline-only"],
    deps = [
        ":utils",
        "//other/stuff:etc",
        # This is the above target for the wheel
        "@pypi__tensorflow_python3_deps//:c_api",
    ],
    alwayslink = 1,
    linkopts = ["-Wl,--whole-archive"],
)
```

The `:c_api` target is enough to get custom ops working, and the C++ code that's failing still compiles and runs, it just doesn't have the required factories registered, so fails when they'd be needed.

What do I need to change to have the registration pattern that TensorFlow uses actually execute?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/BUILD#L769 might be relevant, but it's unclear why that file isn't in the resulting python wheel.

Answer (score 1):

`--whole-archive` does not work in this case. Whole purpose of this flag is to link everything from a **static** library (`*.a` in linux). Shared library by default contains all of the compiled code, so you do not that trick, because you are using `*.so` file.

Perhaps the problem is related to the usage of the `tensorflow_wrapper`. If you link to that library from the bazel like that:

```py
cc_binary(
  name="some_binary",
  src=["main.cpp"],
  deps=["//some/path/to:tensorflow_wrapper"],
)
```

then everything should work fine, because bazel know what is needed by the `tensorflow_wrapper`

However, if you want to use it outside the bazel then it is necessary to link both `libtensorflow_framework.so.2` and `libtensorflow_wrapper.so`/`libtensorflow_wrapper.a` like that:

```sh
g++ your_binary_main.cpp -ltensorflow_wrapper -ltensorflow_framework
```

Comment: Unfortunately, we already are using a `cc_binary` similar to what you suggest, and it doesn't work.